# WCF RestFul service increasing response time with number of concurrent users

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I am fairly new to WCF. I have created a WCF RestFul service which internally has a call to google geocoding api service and a database call. As the number of concurrent users are increased, there is a drastic increase in the average response time. I am using SoapUI for performance testing. Below is a table for the variation in average response time. Could someone please advise on what might be going wrong and what all things I need to consider to get Response time < 5 sec for upto 100 threads. Thanks in advance.

```
(No. of Threads/Sec)    (Response Time in msec Run 1)   (Response Time in msec Run 2)   (Response Time in msec Run 3)
1 user                      1490                        517                                         585
2 users                     2264.5                      785.5                                       853.5
3 users                     1341.33                     1124                                        1093.33
4 users                     2479.75                     1400.25                                     1317
5 users                     2348.6                      1432.4                                      1673.4
8 users                     4818.25                     2130.25                                     4726.3
10 users                    7510.8                      8518.2                                      7655.4
15 users                    11869.26                    12933.93                                    10592.2
20 users                    13510.4                     6319.75                                     14553.1
25 users                    17695.6                     17695.6                                     17695.6
35 users                    20905.17                    19823.2                                     21936.5
50 users                    26235.25                    26146.32                                    31645.87
100 users                   38424.488                   37417.6                                     39465
```

- Edit:

***Web.Config***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="user" value="Mahesh" />
    <add key="GeoCodingErrorDesc" value="GeoCodingErrorDesc." />
    <add key="GeoCodingErrorCode" value="1111" />
    <add key="CacheEmptyErrorDesc" value="CacheEmptyErrorDesc." />
    <add key="CacheEmptyErrorCode" value="2222" />
    <add key="DATAValidationErrorDesc" value="Schema valiation failed for the input recieved." />
    <add key="DATAValidationErrorCode" value="5555" />
    <add key="GenericErrorDesc" value="GenericErrorDesc." />
    <add key="GenericErrorCode" value="3333" />
    <add key="GeoCodingAPIKey" value="*****" />
    <add key="Geocountry" value="|country:IN" />
    <add key="GeoCodingAPIUrl" value="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=" />    
    <add key="Connectionstring" value="Data Source = MachineName; Integrated Security=True;" />
    <add key="Query" value="SELECT * FROM Table where Code IN " />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_ITwoWayAsyncVoid" />
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost/ESB.ExceptionHandlingServices.WCF/ExceptionHandling.svc"
        binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_ITwoWayAsyncVoid"
        contract="ExceptionHandlingService.ExceptionHandling" name="WSHttpBinding_ITwoWayAsyncVoid">        
      </endpoint>
    </client>
    <services>      
      <service name="SearchRequest">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="web" contract="ISearchRequest">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>       
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Search/SearchRequest.svc" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

My interface looks as below,

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface ISearchRequest
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "")]
        Stream GetList(Stream value);
    }
```

Comment: Not enough information was provided. You should share your web.config, and, if you can, the service code as well.

Comment: I have edited the post to include web.config and interface. The code has got bunch of LINQ queries, External call for GeoCoding API and Database call.

Comment: Well, i don't see anything necessarily evil in the web.config. Consider posting the service implementation.